# Can one have US, Italian and French citizenship, triple citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

I have US citizenship since birth, then acquired Italian citizenship through naturalization and now applied for French. Someone told me that I could NOT have triple citizenship as the French government would not accept it. Any answers?

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia page on [French Nationality Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nationality_law)

> Dual citizenship was officially recognized for both men and women on 9
>   January 1973; since then, possession of more than one nationality does
>   not affect French nationality

Answer (score 1):

Most countries that accept multiple citizenship do so by not restricting the possession of other nationalities.  Such countries generally do not place a limit on the number of other nationalities a citizen may possess.  [France is no exception](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F334):

> Il est possible en France d'avoir plusieurs nationalités (double-nationalité par exemple). Cette situation résulte du fait que chaque État fixe de manière souveraine les conditions d'octroi de sa nationalité. Il est possible d'avoir plusieurs nationalités dès sa naissance ou plus tard.

Translation:

> In France, it is possible to have multiple nationality (dual nationality, for example). This situation arises from the fact that each country determines under its own sovereignty the conditions for granting its own nationality.  It is possible to have multiple nationality from one's birth or from a later time.

The other question is whether your naturalization in France would cause you to lose Italian or US citizenship, and the answer to that is generally *no.*